# Can I store a static instance of an Activity or Fragment within itself?

Tags: java, android, static, broadcastreceiver

I need to update a UI element based off a BroadcastReceiver. Is there anything wrong with self referentially storing the last instance created of itself to send the update to?

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static ExampleFragment sExampleFragment = null; 
    private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkReceiver;    
    private TextView networkStateTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sExampleFragment = this;
        mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
        registerNetworkBroadcast();        
    }

    public void updateTextView(Boolean value) {
        networkStateTextView.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public static void setNetworkConnectedState(boolean value){        
        sExampleFragment.updateTextView(value);
    }

    private void registerNetworkBroadcast() {
        getContext().registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }

    protected void unregisterNetworkChanges() {
        try {
            getContext().unregisterReceiver(mNetworkReceiver);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My broadcast receiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        try
        {
            Log.d("Network Available ", String.valueOf(isOnline(context)));
            ExampleFragment.setNetworkConnectedState(isOnline(context));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            //should check null because in airplane mode it will be null
            return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to does this without polluting my Fragment with static members?

Comment: Do not hold `Context` statically it will cause memory leak .

Comment: can you paste the complete code here

Comment: @ADM there would only be at most 1 context copy. right?

Comment: `BroadcastReceiver` is a Component so it already have the `Context` . Use `sendBroadcast()` to notify do not use public methods .

Comment: Bad design. Memory leaks. `BroadcastReceiver` is your friend.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher I've added my broadcast receiver code. what needs to be done to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: @KushaalSingla I've added more code

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Monitor network changed events
        mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                try
                {
                    Log.d("Network Available ", String.valueOf(isOnline(context)));
                    ///networkChanged(isOnline(context));

                    if(isOnline(context)){
                        connectedImageView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_connected_yes));
                        connectedTextView.setText(R.string.connected_yes);
                    }else{
                        connectedImageView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_connected_no));
                        connectedTextView.setText(R.string.connected_no);
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```